# Antd Date : how to set valid empty date in moment js

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, antd

I am using ANTD (https://ant.design/) for the project, ANTD is working fine with other components whereas I am facing issue while using DatePicker(https://ant.design/components/date-picker/).
DatePicker uses moment(https://momentjs.com/)

In a form initially, I want all the fields with a placeholder and once the user fills the form it will be displayed to him/her. Once added user can edit their data.

Setting data works fine but I am unable to set date field initially as empty so that I am able to show the user a field with a placeholder

I am setting the date field as

```
initialValue: moment(null) => invalid date
initialValue: moment('') => invalid date
initialValue: moment(undefined) => current date // i don't want current date i want empty (to show the placeholder instead)
```

where as when i am getting user selected while setting the date it works perfectly fine.

```
 initialValue: moment(userSelectedDate) =>  user selected date
```

Comment: Have you tried not providing the `initialValue` prop?

Comment: I am using initialValue prop for setting the data ,
if I removed that then it works fine but then I am  unable to set the user date while showing the form for edit
@ghostbbbmt-MSP

Comment: If you want to not set the initial value, does not provide the `initialValue` prop

Comment: I am handling the initial form and edit form in the same form if I don't use initialValue prop then I won't be able to set the data while showing the using edit form

Comment: Post a demo in a sandbox... the problem is with how you handling the form.

Comment: @Wasif you can use state like `selectedDate` and set `initialValue = this.state.selectedDate`. Try to set the init value of `selectedDate` is `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
              <Space direction="horizontal">
            <DatePicker
              value={formik.values.next_reminder_date
                ? moment(formik.values.next_reminder_date) : undefined}
              placeholder="Next Reminder Date"
              name="next_reminder_date"
              onChange={(date) => {
                const isoDate = date?.toISOString();
                formik.setFieldValue('next_reminder_date', isoDate);
              }}
            />
          </Space>
```

Comment: Just want to say you're the greatest.

Answer (score 1):

Make an initial value in `state` as `undefined` and assign an initial value to `defaultValue` prop of `datepicker`. 
Try the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';

const dateFormat = 'YYYY/MM/DD';
const initialValue=undefined; // this initial value should be in state

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Form.Item >
      {getFieldDecorator('password', {
        rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
        initialValue:initialValue
      })(
        <DatePicker
      placeholder="please add date"
     format={dateFormat}
/>
      )}
    </Form.Item>

    <br />

  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container'),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
<DatePicker
        
        placeholder="Date"
        format={DATE_FORMAT}
        defaultValue={
          (data?.openHouse?.date && moment(data.openHouse?.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) || ''
        }
        onChange={(momentDate: any) => {
          setValue('openHouse.date', momentDate?.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), {
            shouldValidate: true,
          });
        }}
        
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

instead

```
initialValue: moment(null)
```

pass

```
initialValue: undefined.
```

works for me,

Answer (score 0):

```
const getDateFormat = date => {
    var d = moment(date);
    return date && d.isValid() ? d : '';
  };
```

In your input tag value={getDateFormat(value)}